# Confusion in the use of putchar() function in C

Tags: c, putchar

I am learning C form the book, 'The C programming language'. In that when it was introducing putchar() function using the code as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
/* program to copy its input to its
   output, one character at a time
   using assignment inside while loop */

    int main()
    {
            int c;
            while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
                    putchar(c);
    }
```

Initially I thought that if I want to input '123\n' and for this when I press key '1' then on in the terminal '11' will be visible to me, and so after pressing key '2' and '3' I thought that the terminal will show '112233' and when I finally hit 'enter' then there will be two new lines. But I was wrong and the input was printed only when I hit 'enter' or 'EOF'.

There was another problem in book, to print those lines whose length is more than 80 characters. I wrote the following code, hoping that it will work:

```
    #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int c, nc=0;
        while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
        {
                ++nc;
                if(c=='\n')
                {       
                        if(nc > 80)
                                putchar(c);
                        nc=0;
                }
        }
}
```

But this is not working.

In the first code when I hit 'enter' then that prints the complete line, in the second code I wanted to count the characters and when I hit 'enter' my code checks whether the character count is more than 80 or not, and if more than 80 then I have done 'putchar(c)'. Why this is not working?

Please be clear that I am not asking for the solution of the problem in book. I am confused by the output of 'putchar()', kindly clear my doubt.

Comment: Regarding your first question: This is the behavior of ISO C. If you want your program to react to keypresses without pressing ENTER, you will have to use platform-specific extensions. For example, Microsoft Windows offers the functions [`_getche`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getche-getwche?view=vs-2019) and [`kbhit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=vs-2019). Linux offers similar features.

Comment: More answers and links at [How to avoid pressing Enter with getchar() for reading a single character only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-pressing-enter-with-getchar-for-reading-a-single-character-only).

Comment: The standard streams are normally buffered. So in this case getchar is reading from the stand input stream (i.e. stdin) but your input gets stored in a buffer until a new line or EOF is encountered. You can do a internet search for something like "I/O buffering in C" for more information.

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17552458/94687

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that may effect when input characters are available to `getchar()`:

1. If the C standard library detects that *standard input* stream is *not* connected to an "interactive device" (e.g. not connected to a terminal window), it will set the stream to *fully buffered mode*, otherwise it will be set to *line buffered* mode. (The same is true for the *standard output* stream, but the *standard error* stream will not be set to fully buffered mode.) (See C11 [7.21.3p3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p7) The buffering mode of a stream can be changed using the `setvbuf()`, or `setbuf()` functions. (Some systems have additional functions, but they are usually just wrappers around `setvbuf().)
2. If the standard input is coming from a POSIX tty, it will normally be set to *canonical input* mode, meaning that input is made available to be read line by line. For POSIX, the [termios](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/termios.h.html) settings can be changed to put the terminal into *noncanonical* input mode where input can be read character by character. (Microsoft Windows console windows have the [SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) function for similar settings.) These functions operate below the level of C streams.